# What do I need to do and repair where these 3M strips pulled off

Tags: drywall, damage

I live in a mature apartment complex, by mature I mean the complex was built in the late '60 early '70s. Only God knows how many actual coats of paint are on the wall(s).

This 3M shelf fell one night when it was extremely hot and humid. The shelf was not overweight, it only had a couple of photos on it that was it.

The one photo I included I used a typical house key for size reference. I've never made a repair like this, so I'd need to know what items I'd need to do the repair and how to repair it.[image: 3m strip pulled away from wall]

I appreciate the help, immensely! I miss that little shelf!

Comment: To clarify - an adhesive mount shelf made by 3M, the sticky things company, not a 3 meter long shelf? Perhaps add a picture of the shelf that fell off to make it more clear...

Comment: I think that section of wall you're looking at is likely to be a fair indicator of the general condition of the state of paint adhesion pretty much everywhere. It looks to me as though multiple layers of paint have pulled off, and that it's one of the (many) lower layers which has separated from whatever is underneath. As such, you're probably going to have the same problem no matter where you re-stick your shelf - it's going to fall down again sooner or later due to the underlying paint layer adhesion issue...

Comment: Non-sequitir PSA: 3M Command products only work if the **removal** is done using the weird trick specified in the instructions, and very carefully and precisely.

Comment: Like... don't post high-resolution photos of keys on the internet, especially if they are yours.

Answer (score 6):

Is this paper?

[image]

If not then [crip659's answer](https://diy.stackexchange.com/a/253261/42053) should work fine but you should also apply mud.

---

If it is paper then don't mud it directly or else it can blister.

Follow crip659's answer but before mudding you should seal it with a layer of wood glue.

Watch https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SkowpaB_IAc for more info.

Answer (score 5):

Remove all the loose paint from the wall. Any paint that pulls from the wall just by finger nails.

Sand the edges out so you have a nice feathered(very low slope), should not be able to feel the difference from old paint to bare wall by fingertips. Use primer and then paint to match.

I probably would put a picture(mirror, poster, clock) up there to hide the patch, since it will be easier than to get exact colour match.  When the whole wall is painted again, the patch will disappear.

Comment: Assuming the asker will live in said apartment for another number of years, this might also be a good excuse to just do the full room and eliminate the problem completely. Otherwise stuff might peel off again in a while.

Comment: Cool!  Thanks much!  I can just hit the maintenance guys up for a little jar of paint they use.  Would I be OK to use a spray can primer?  I don't need a gallon of that stuff laying around here.

Comment: @DaveHandler  Should be able to buy primer in smaller cans than by the gallon.  A friendly local painter might even trade you a pint of primer for a pint of beer.

Comment: You wouldn't want spray can primer @Dave... all spray can products are alkyd ("oil") based, and they stink to high heaven for days. Vastly higher performance, but boy do they stink. (I myself use 2-part epoxy primers that stink even worse, but once they're done stinking, last 20 years *on a boat* lol.)